# How do I catch the fairy in the sealed grounds?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I can't seem to catch the fairy that floats in the sealed grounds. I tried running and jumping to catch it in my bottle, but it doesn't work. It's too high to scoop. What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have an empty bottle, you can catch faries in your Bug Net.

Comment: Good tip but i don't have the bug net yet...

Comment: @Toomai Cool, I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to catch fairies, in  my opinion, is to get your bottle out when you're not too close to the fairy. Approach slowly and Z-target it as soon as you can. The best time to swing is when the tip at the bottom appears ("`A` Catch").

The targeting will ensure that Link gets to the right height for a successful catch. Be careful not to approach too fast, as you might miss the right timing and get instant healed instead.